# jQuery How call function only if 2 inputs & 1 select are set or updated?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm trying to call a function only when 3 inputs (2 input, 1 select dropdown menu) are set with a specific value. The form contains multiples inputs, select & checkboxes. This call is perform before the form is sent.

- The first input is a select / dropdown menu.
- The second one is standard input which should be check only when it does have at least 1 digit (up to no limit), a dot and then 1 digit. Sample: 19212.6
- The third is a hidden input which value shall be bigger than 1.

I know the .change function in jQuery shall help me but I don't know how to tune it properly for my settings. On top of that, if the inputs match the mentioned filter above, it should run afterwards a MsSQL Query (PHP).

```
$('input').change(function(){
}
```

The code is mixed with PHP.
At the moment, I've created 3 changes (1 for each input/Select) which call a function and check if all the values are compliant.
Is it a better, nice & clean way to do this?

Part of code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
    $( ".gdctype" ).change(function() {
        var gdc = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        if (gdc == "UK"){
            $('.ilsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.casel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.bslsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.rusel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uspsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uksel').removeAttr('style');
        }
        if (gdc == "IL"){
            $('.uksel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.casel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.bslsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.rusel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uspsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.ilsel').removeAttr('style');
        }
        if (gdc == "CA"){
            $('.uksel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.ilsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.bslsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.rusel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uspsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.casel').removeAttr('style');
        }
        if (gdc == "BSL"){
            $('.uksel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.ilsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.casel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.rusel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uspsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.bslsel').removeAttr('style');
        }
        if (gdc == "RU"){
            $('.uksel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.ilsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.casel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.bslsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uspsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.rusel').removeAttr('style');
        }
        if (gdc == "US"){
            $('.uksel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.ilsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.casel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.bslsel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.rusel').css({ 'display': 'none'});
            $('.uspsel').removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

        var uniquePUS = <?php if($uniquePUS!=NULL) echo $uniquePUS;?> <?php if($uniquePUS==NULL) echo "1";?>;
      $('.addPUS').click(function() {
        var copy = $('#PUS').clone(true,true);
        var formId = 'PUS' + window.uniquePUS;
        copy.attr('id', formId );
        copy.removeAttr('style');

        copy.find(':input#PUSAddress').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' id='" + $(this).attr("id") + window.uniquePUS+"' id='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniquePUS+"' >");
        });

        copy.find(':input#PUSCity').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='" + $(this).attr("id") + window.uniquePUS+"' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniquePUS + "' />");
        });

        copy.find(':input#PUSState').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='" + $(this).attr("id") + window.uniquePUS+"' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniquePUS + "' size=2 />");
        });

        copy.find(':input#PUSZip').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='" + $(this).attr("id") + window.uniquePUS+"' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + window.uniquePUS + "' size=4 />");
        });
        $('#uspselin').append(copy);
        window.uniquePUS++;  
        $('#main').find(':input#uniquePUS').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith("<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' id='uniquePUS' name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "' value='"+window.uniquePUS+"' />");
        });

      });
    $('.delPUS').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("ul").remove();
    });  
        function chktrp(nr){
        if(nr != null && nr != undefined){
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/);
            return pattern.test(nr);    
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    function chkfields(){
        if (
            $('select[name="gdctype"]').val() == 'US'
            &&
            $('input[name="uniquePUS"]').val() > '0'
            &&
            chktrp($('input[name="Trip"]').val())
        ) {
            return true;

      }else{
        return false;}
    }
    $('input[name="Trip"]').change(function(){
        if (chkfields()){
            alert('Works1');
        }
    });
    $('input[name="uniquePUS"]').change(function(){
        if (chkfields()){
            alert('Works2');
        }
    });
    $('select[name="gdctype"]').change(function(){
        if (chkfields()){
            alert('Works3');
        }
    });
});
```

I can add the HTML code if relevant.

Comment: you could have separate JavaScript file, Separate php script/class  which have functions to run queries and other stuffs. Then call appropriate function via ajax when particular criteria is met. Please tell us what do you want to know exactly and what you have done up to now.

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried to accomplish what you want?

Comment: This sounds perfect. I'd like to update the form before it's submitted based on what the user selects.
What I'm trying to accomplish is a kind of complex form which generates different types of documents based on what you select.
Once the fields are choosen and the file number is set (sample 19212.6), a SQL query is ran and return, row numbers matching that the query, names and another function will be ran in order to add more features to the form (div, checkboxes, etc).
By now, I'm only working with the $('input').change(function(){} after document is ready ( $(document).ready(function () {)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a form field like this :

```
$('input[name="inputName"]').val()
```

One you know that you can test your fields :

```
if (
    $('input[name="inputName"]').val() != ''
    &&
    $('input[name="inputName2"]').val() > 2
) {
    .... call your function
}
```

Comment: Looks nice but works only once the form is sent and page is reloaded. Any way to do it live before the form is sent?